# Firebase query giving null at StartAt kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

The query variable gives a null value. But when I comment out startAt(input), it works fine and gives all the user names from the database. input variable is basically one letter at a time in the editview. Any suggestions as to why startAt() does not work?

```
view.search_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            searchUsers("Al")
         }
    })

private fun searchUsers(input: String) {
    val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
        .orderByChild("fullname")
        .startAt("Al")
        .endAt("Al"+ "\uf8ff")

    //query to print results in adapter
    query.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(datasnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            //datasnapshot.value should be Alan but instead is null so it doesn't enter the for loop
            for(snapshot in datasnapshot.children) {
                val u = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                if(u != null) {
                    user.add(u)
                }
            }
            userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        } 
}
```

And the User JSON looks like this-

```
{
    "Users" : {
       "AbMN5lIjg5OPf3MCzbBz2TqxcP90" : {
           "bio" : "Bio1",
           "email" : "brian01@gmail.com",
           "fullname" : "Brian Carter",
           "uid" : "AbMN5lIjg5OPf3MCzbBz2TqxcP90",
           "username" : "brian01"
       },
       "BqMN4lIjg9PXe3QXzwWz2TqegP63" : {
           "bio" : "Bio2",
           "email" : "alan55@gmail.com",
           "fullname" : "Alan Taylor",
           "uid" : "BqMN4lIjg9PXe3QXzwWz2TqegP63",
           "username" : "alan55"
       }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to: 1) include the JSON at `Users` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) the code that actually executes the query and prints the results. 3) the output of that code.

Comment: Please edit the question with the info the Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also respond with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited my question by providing the JSON at Users, the query code. There's no output since the datasnapshot valu is null.

Comment: Thanks the update. What is the value of `input`? Note that it's much easier to help if you reproduce the problem with hard-coded values, and have clear debugging output (like, does your `onDataChange` get called? Is your `onCancelled` called?)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen input is basically a string which is typed one letter at a time. For example, I start by typing 'a' and then 'l', then 'a' and so on. So for each of these inputs I would want Alan Taylor to display. Also it is to be noted that this piece of code gets called inside `onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int)` in a `addTextChangedListener`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my `onDataChange` does get called but the for loop inside it does not. `onCancelled` also works fine, just hadn't included it here.

Comment: Searching for `.orderByChild("fullname").startAt("ala").endAt("ala\uf8ff")` will **not** return `"fullname" : "Alan Taylor"` as queries are case sensitive. Note that its best to reproduce the problem with hard-coded values, so that we can save ourselves some back and forth over what is typed in the UI.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've updated the code. But again, my main problem is with `startAt()`, because then the rest of my code works without it. I hope you've got the jist of it and where it's failing.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any suggestions?

Comment: I imported your data into a database of mine, and tried reproducing it in JavaScript without success: https://jsbin.com/lamuxot/edit?js,console. I've never seen the Android and JavaScript SDK give difference results on this type of operation, so am not sure why you're seeing something else.